# How to add workflow in Alfresco manually..?

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I am working with Alfresco as Back-end and in alfresco some task done by executing workflow.Now my problem is **I want to add workflow in alfresco manually but i don't know where to put workflow script so i will choose from work space ?**

Following picture describes my problem :

I reached below point but don't know what to do further ?

[image]

According to above picture **From where these bunch of files are came..?? OR At which location i will find these files in project workspace?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login as admin in alfresco.
Navigate to **Company home>Data dictionary>Scripts**

You will be able to see all these files.
If you upload any of your js file then it will be automatically pickedup and addedinto this list.

Answer (score 2):

You will find them in Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts.